# My laptop's keyboard suddenly stopped working! How do I fix it?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

I've got a Sony VAIO laptop, with a touch screen monitor. I was using it yesterday with no problems at all. I turned it off. My daughter turned it on and tried to log in, but the keyboard wouldn't respond at all. This is very serious to me. Honestly we're suspecting some change recently. I know that there were updates to that machine that Microsoft pushed out. I've been updates going onto our desktops too, as everything is getting ready for the imminent launch of Windows 10. Could some update have caused my laptop to have the problem that it is having? I guess a better question is, supposing it is some update that's gone awry with one of more updates, how do I determine which one and fix it or get rid of it?

Comment: When you say you turned it off, did you shutdown, sleep or hibernate? May need a cold boot.

Answer (score 0):

Go control panel. Device manager. Find keyboard. Uninstall. Then click on refresh to find any hardware which not installed. Windows will automatically install keyboard again. Check if it solved